# /.rbenv/versions/ doesn't exist for user installed 1.8.7-p374

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, rbenv

`~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/` exists as does a similar folder for 1.9.3-p429, but nothing for 1.8.7-p374.

What is going on or what am I doing wrong? I have some gems that don't work right with 1.9 and 2.0, so set up 1.8.7-p374 to help debug, but can't install gems.

```
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 1.8.7-p374 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
  1.9.3-p429
  2.0.0-p195
$ gem install geonames
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/user_name/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/geonames-0.3.3/.gitignore
```

I can sudo and install the gem, but I don't know where, and it's not available.

I'm lost in rbenv. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have set `RBENV_VERSION` in your environment, e.g. in your `~/.bashrc` (look for `export RBENV_VERSION=1.8.7-p374`), but that particular Ruby version is not installed.

To proceed, first remove that `export` line and secondly install Ruby 1.8.7 like so:

```
$ rbenv install 1.8.7-p374
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

No .bashrc. Only similar file is .bash_profile which reads

`export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby version `1.8.7` generally comes pre-installed with the operating system. That is the reason you do not see it under rbenv's directory